# Can't find referenced class / Can't find referenced method

Tags: android, proguard

I thought I kind of understood proguard `keep` rules but I guess I don't! I have some rules of the following form in my proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class de.neom.neoreadersdk.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class android.** { *; }
```

I'd expect all classes and class members in the above packages to not be obfuscated (i.e. for the names to not be modified by proguard). However, I'm seeing the following warnings (and lots more besides) when proguard is run:

> ... [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.es: can't find
> referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)'
> in class android.webkit.WebSettings
>
> ... [proguard] Warning:
> de.neom.neoreadersdk.Viewfinder14View$AdView: can't find referenced
> class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
>
> ... [proguard] Warning:
> org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class
> org.joda.convert.FromString

Should I be worried by these warnings? What rules should I be adding to my proguard configuration to correct the issues that these warnings are alerting me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your libraries are referring to methods or classes that are missing from the target run-time or from the other libraries, e.g. org.joda.convert.FromString. If your application works fine anyway, you can tell ProGuard it's okay. For instance:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for the response. Clicking that link just takes me to the Proguard home page?! Do you happen to know how I can navigate to that link from the home page?